# I've followed all the instructions in a tutorial for a bot, and why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, discord.py

This code i'm using to try to make a discord bot that will change people's nicknames in my server for them, won't work.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import embeds
from discord import message
import random
from typing import ValuesView
import os
from discord.ext.commands.core import has_guild_permissions

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='g!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Gilbert is now online!')

@client.command(pass_content=True)
async def changenick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    await ctx.send(f'Nickname has been changed for {member.mention}.')

client.run=('mydiscordtoken')
```

[Here's what my terminal and member list look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8WDN.png)

Comment: Your error messages and output should be in the text of the question itself, not in a screenshot.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.run` is not a variable, as you have treated it in your question, but instead more similar to a function. Replacing your last line with the following should fix your problem.

```py
client.run('mydiscordtoken')
```

Comment: thank you very much, i'm sorry if I asked one of the dumb questions, I just couldn't for the life of me figure it out. Thank you 